# Error in Functions. php file

Tags: php

All my drafts in my wordpress blog now have the following error :

> Warning: stripos() [function.stripos]: needle is not a string or an
>   integer in
>   /home/brightonkeller/brightontheday.com/wp-includes/functions.php on
>   line 658
>
> Warning: stripos() [function.stripos]: needle is not a string or an
>   integer in
>   /home/brightonkeller/brightontheday.com/wp-includes/functions.php on
>   line 661

anybody have any idea what this means or what to do? I saw a few other threads on the topic but I was nervous to tinker with any of the functions.php files of my theme.

Comment: The warning is because there is something wrong with the code that is calling `stripos()`. However, without posting those lines of code and the lines surrounding them, nobody can help.

Comment: The error tells you EXACTLY what the problem is.  You are invoking `stripos()` while passing a non-string, non-integer value for the needle.  Just `var_dump()` that value for the variables you are using with these functions to find out what you are actually passing.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not well versed in what all this means. How can I paste the code? What should I do? I have NO idea.

Comment: @Brighton Just copy your code and paste it at the bottom of your question, highlight your code then press the `{}` curly bracket icon in the toolbar for indentation and syntax highlighting, if it doesn't work properly then someone will edit it for you. Just make that you only include the applicable code.

Comment: @asok I feel so stupid. I can't figure out where to find the code. when i inspect element in chrome, i can't figure out how to find the javascript, rather than the html? or even when i click view pagesource, I can't find it?

Comment: @Brighton No worries, the issue is with PHP which wouldn't show in a view source or inspect element. You'll need to have access to the webhost provided file manager through cPanel. Then navigate to `wp-includes` folder and then open the `functions.php` file. You'll need some sort of PHP IDE or text editor (preferably one that shows line numbers), then go down to line 658 and get the surrounding code (include line 661)

Comment: @asok you are so nice. thank you. going to try to do now.

Comment: @Brighton Actually you shouldn't need to paste code, when I was typing my last comment I realized that this is WordPress and started to do a little research. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @asok  if ( $frag = strstr( $uri, '#' ) )
    $uri = substr( $uri, 0, -strlen( $frag ) );
  else
    $frag = '';

  if ( 0 === stripos( 'http://', $uri ) ) {
    $protocol = 'http://';
    $uri = substr( $uri, 7 );
  } elseif ( 0 === stripos( 'https://', $uri ) ) {
    $protocol = 'https://';
    $uri = substr( $uri, 8 );
  } else {
    $protocol = '';
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It seems like a few people are having the exact same issue, click here to read what they are discussing](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-an-error-5).

---

**Possible resolution:**

I would contact your webhost by opening a support ticket and ask them to upgrade your php version to 5.3 at least.

---

Before contacting them you could verify your php version by creating a file in your root `public_html` directory, name it something like `myphp.php` and then add the following to the file:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Then navigate to the page by going to brightontheday.com/myphp.php - You will see the version at the very top of the page (**Note**: Some webhosts disable this functionality, so you may see an error or access denied message.) Once you have seen it then delete that file you just created (myphp.php).

Comment: Let me know if you get it working or not. Hope this helps.

Comment: ok I did this. I think it should take like 15-20 minutes. How do you know these things? I'm so jealous! I would have NEVER figured this out. I am so appreciative.

Comment: the error is still showing up though. fyi. @asok

Comment: FIXED!!!!!!!!! I am so thankful! @asok do you have a webpage? or a twitter? I would love to support you in some way

Comment: Wonderful, glad I could help! :) I am currently developing a webpage, nothing published yet though. Most of my work is internal web applications and in-house Android applications for my employer. If you wouldn't mind clicking on the check mark on my answer to accept it, that will be support enough :). Best wishes!